# Pythonic way to assign the parameter into attribute?

Tags: python, oop, class, methods

The sample codes are like this:

```
def assign(self, input=None, output=None, param=None, p1=None, p2=None):
    if input:
        self.input = input
    if output:
        self.output = output
    if param:
        self.param = param
    if p1:
        self.p1 = p1
    if p2:
        self.p2 = p2
```

Though this looks very clear, it suffers if there're 10 parameters for this function. Does anyone have ideas about a more convinient way for this?

Comment: As a side note, there's a potential problem with your code: What if you want to actually assign the value `None`? If that matters, you can get around this by creating a sentinel value (e.g., `sentinel = object()`, then `input=sentinel, output=sentinel, …` in the parameters, then check `if input is not sentinel` instead of `if input`).

Comment: @abarnert I see. Changed into `**kwargs` way, I don't need to care about sentinel now.

Comment: No problem. As I said, it's just a "potential problem". If there's no valid false-y value (`None`, `0`, `''`, `[]`, etc.) you'd ever want to store in your attributes, this is perfectly fine.

Comment: I posted an answer for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
def assign(self,**kwargs):
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        if v:
           setattr(self,k,v)
```

This is quite simple and suitable for many situations.  If you want to maintain a set of keywords which you'll accept and raise TypeError for the rest:

```
#python2.7 and newer
def assign(self,allowed_kwargs={'foo','bar','baz'},**kwargs):
    if kwargs.keysview() - allowed_kwargs:
        raise TypeError('useful message here...')
    for k in allowed_kwargs:
        setattr(self,k,kwargs[k])
```

This is somewhat inspect-able as well since the user will see the set of allowed kwargs.

Comment: Be careful with `if v:`.  This will not set the attribute for any value that is not considered `True` in python.  So `obj.assign(a=0, b='', c=[])` will not assign any of those attributes to `obj`.  I think `if v is not None:` would be safer.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser -- That's a reasonable point.  I answered this way to mirror OP's original code, but it's nice to have this noted here.

Comment: With your solution, it is mandatory to pass arguments in the keyworded form. In my answer, it's not.

Answer (score 1):

*Explicit is better than implicit*

```
def assign(self, input=None, output=None, param=None, p1=None, p2=None):
```

has many advantages over

```
def assign(self, **kwargs)
```

- It is self-documenting
- A helpful `TypeError` is raised if an invalid parameter is passed to
  `assign`.
- `assign` can be called with positional as well as keyword arguments

To its credit, the code the OP posted is entirely explicit, though the `if`-statements are monotonous. To cut down on the monotony,
you could use something like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def assign(self, input=None, output=None, param=None, p1=None, p2=None):
        for name in 'input output param p1 p2'.split():
            val = vars()[name]
            if val is not None:
                setattr(self, name, val)

foo = Foo()
foo.assign(p1=123, p2='abc')
```

Comment: If you want to reproduce his `assign` function, you should raise a `TypeError` for any `key not in kwargs` instead of just skipping it. Also, I think it's more general (e.g., works with `__slots__`), and probably more explicit, to call `setattr` instead of `self.__dict__.__update`.

Comment: Decorators are ignored when touching __dict__ directly.  So if a person were to use `@property` and `@x.setter` for something, this would break that.  the `setattr` call fixes this (like abarnert mentioned.)

Comment: @BlackVegetable: Yeah, I was just trying to give one example of when `setattr` is necessary. There's also custom descriptors, `__setattr__`, superclasses with some of these same issues, superclasses implemented in C/RPython/Java/.NET with similar issues, …

Comment: What do you think of my answer, please ?

Comment: @eyquem: I get the sense you are trying to solve a different, more complicated, problem than the one Firegun has asked. I'm not convinced of the validity of the problem, so I am not enthusiastic about the solution. (I like simple things; your solution is too complex.) However, I do like the fact that you've retained an explicit call signature; I've changed my answer because of it.

Comment: This is nice, but it isn't "DRY" approved.  Also, I believe with this you'll get an extra `foo.name` attribute which you probably don't want.  You could regain *most* of this stuff in my answer by only setting a list of approved keys as a simple modification.  You could also raise a TypeError `if kwargs.keysview() - set_of_approved_keys`

Comment: @mgilson: Where is the extra `foo.name` coming from? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @unutbu -- sorry.  You're right.  I was thinking you were looping over `vars()` for some reason (but my logic in that case was flawed as well).  for the benefit of others and to be 100% clear, this answer does **NOT** add a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

One of the great things about python is its interactive interpreter.  When you write code like this:

```
>>> def assign(self, input=None, output=None, param=None, p1=None, p2=None):
...     pass
...
```

Its quite easy to figure out how you're supposed to use the function:

```
>>> help(assign)
Python Library Documentation: function assign in module __main__

assign(self, input=None, output=None, param=None, p1=None, p2=None)
```

By comparison:

```
>>> def assign2(self, **kwargs):
...     pass
...
```

gives:

```
>>> help(assign2)
Python Library Documentation: function assign2 in module __main__

assign2(self, **kwargs)
```

I hope you understand why the first form is preferrable.  But you still want to avoid writing everything twice (in the arguments and in the body).

The first question is *why* are you writing code of this nature?  I find it a very common case that I want a class with a heap of attributes that it will carry around, but the set of those attributes is essentially fixed.  In the very most common case, those attributes never change for the lifetime of the object; in which case python has a built in helper for exactly that!

```
>>> import collections
>>> Assignment = collections.namedtuple('Assignment', 'input output param p1 p2')
>>> assign = Assignment(None, None, None, None, None)._replace
>>> assign(p1=10)
Assignment(input=None, output=None, param=None, p1=10, p2=None)
>>> help(Assignment)
Python Library Documentation: class Assignment in module __main__

class Assignment(__builtin__.tuple)
 |  Assignment(input, output, param, p1, p2)
 |  
... SNIP
```

`namedtuple`'s are regular classes, you can inherit from them to give them special behaviours.  they are, unfortunately, immutable, and if you happen to need that, you will need another technique; but you should almost always reach for named tuple first.  Otherwise, we can make use of some other magic; we can get all of the local variables, which at function start, includes only the arguments:

```
>>> class Assignable(object):
...     def assign(self, input=None, output=None, param=None, p1=None, p2=None):
...         _kwargs = vars()
...         _kwargs.pop('self')
...         vars(self).update((attr, value) for attr, value in _kwargs.items() if value is not None)
... 
>>> a = Assignable()
>>> vars(a)
{}
>>> a.assign(p1=6)
>>> vars(a)
{'p1': 6}
>>> a.p1
6
```

and the `help()` text is still very helpful!

```
>>> help(a.assign)
Python Library Documentation: method assign in module __main__

assign(self, input=None, output=None, param=None, p1=None, p2=None) method of __main__.Assignable instance
```

Comment: Add a docstring ``'''parameters with default value None are: input, output, param, p1, p2'''`` and ``help(assign)`` will display two lines ``assign(self, **kwargs)`` and ``'''parameters with default value None are: input, output, param, p1, p2'''``

Comment: I closely studied your proposition of using a namedtuple. I don't think it's so much interesting that it seems at start: **1)** a named tuple instance has attributes _fields, _make, _asdict besides the ones that the coder certainly wants as the only attributes for its desired instance, they are superfluous info recorded in the instance. **2)** The only useful attribute ``_replace`` has a behavior that may be a drawback: it returns an object having a different identity. That may be unwanted in some cases. This point is covered by what you say when evoking that named tuples are immutable.

Comment: **3)** Point 2 was about changing the values of existing attributes. This one is about adding new attributes: no new attribute can be added after creation of a named tuple, the ``__dict__`` of a named tuple can't be changed. It makes the interest of named tuples: _"Named tuple instances do not have per-instance dictionaries, so they are lightweight and require no more memory than regular tuples."_ , but it makes them not very suitable for other tasks than what they are designed for. My opinion.

Comment: However, your answer made me think about different subjects and I've upvoted other very interesting answers of you (on locals for ex).

Comment: methods which take more than three arguments (other than `self`) are frequently suspect.  The different arguments usually belong together, as a group of related attributes.  the way attributes are normally grouped, in python and other languages, is with a class.  Passing an instance of a light weight class (as returned by `namedtuple`) is a particularly concise and descriptive way to hand data around, even when that data will be applied to another, less light class.   When I say reach for `namedtuple`, I don't mean replace the class that owns `assign()` in this question, only the function.

Comment: Could show a code , please. I don't see how a class must be defined to replace a method with a named tuple. The characteristic of a method is that the first parameter ``self`` receives the instance. I don't see what in a named tuple will designates the instance. Or the instance must be a named tuple itself ? But I still don't see the organization of that.

Comment: @eyquem: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5131239 the point is to reduce the number of arguments in the method; having lots and lots of arguments is an anti-pattern

Comment: 1] You didn't replace the function ``mutateThing()`` by a named tuple, you replaced the function by a function that uses a named tuple. And it needs to be transfomed in a dict by ``_asdict``. There's no difference with a function using directly a kwarg.

Comment: 2] A named tuple must be passed as argument to function ``mutate()``. The first time, it needs to define a named tuple with for example ``mumu = Mutation._make(('aa','bb','cc','dd','ee'))`` and pass ``mumu`` instead of writing directly ``('aa','bb','cc','dd','ee')`` in a call . The following times, if any, it needs to execute ``mumu._replace(wobble=4789)`` for example, and then pass, instead of writing directly ``wobble=4789`` in the call of a method. Where's the advantage ?.

Comment: 3] You are obliged to pass a named tuple containing 5 values, instead of the desired variable number of values. No more, no less. - Really, the more I examine, the less I'm convinced to use a named tuple.

Answer (score 0):

With mgilson's and unutbu's solutions, the possibility of writing all types of calls is lost.

In my following solution, this possibility is preserved:

```
class Buu(object):
    def assign(self,
               input=None, output=None,
               param=None,
               p1=None, p2=None,
               **kw):
        for k,v in locals().iteritems():
            if v not in (self,None,kw):
                if v == (None,):
                    setattr(self,k,None)
                else:
                    setattr(self,k,v)
        for k,v in kw.iteritems():
            setattr(self,k,v)

buu = Buu()

buu.assign(None,(None,), p1=[])
print "buu's attributes:",vars(buu)
print

buu.assign(1,p2 = 555, xx = 'extra')
print "buu's attributes:",vars(buu)
```

result

```
buu's attributes: {'output': None, 'p1': []}

buu's attributes: {'p2': 555, 'output': None, 'xx': 'extra', 'p1': [], 'input': 1}
```

By the way, when a coder puts `None` as default argument for a parameter, it's because he foresees that there will be no case where it will be necessary to pass `None` as a significant arguments that would really be of influence during the excution.
Hence I think that the point of passing `None` as real significant argument is a false problem.
However , in the above code, this problem is skirted by using the convention that in case a new attribute with value `None` must be created, the argument should be `(None,)`.

If someone wants to pass `(None,)` ???
Seriously ?
Oh heck!